# What enabled the Chinese Provence of Shenzhen to grow to 12 million over 30-40 years

Tags: china, city-planning, planning

The Chinese province of [Shenzhen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenzhen) has grown from around 10000 people to being a city of over 12,000,000 between 1980 and 2017

What made this happen, what government policies and investment created this city and what were other factors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too basic - so much so that it's answered in the 2nd paragraph of the page you linked to.

Comment: The article does not directly answer my question.  It can be inferred but there was probably other things such as direct investment in infrastructure etc

Comment: It's a combination of being next to Hong Kong where there was plenty of capital and being one of the first special economic zones after China opened up, with a heavy trend towards massive urbanization and heavy infrastructure investments by China in the background.